# r difference between non-NA column values

Tags: r, missing-data

I need to calculate differences between non-NA values in a row. For example, if there are values only at points a, c, and e, and values in b and d are NA, I need to calculate the difference between c and a, e and c, and leave the difference between b and a and d and c blank. d1 is the difference between non-NA value in b and nearest non-NA value to the left (which has to be non-NA value in a). d2 is the difference between non-NA value in c and nearest non-NA value to the left. d3 is the difference between non-NA value in d and nearest non-NA value to the left. d4 is the difference between non-NA value in e and the nearest non-NA value to the left.

I think I'm missing some R functions that are available to use in this situation. I tried writing a number of ifelse conditions that account for the preceding data point being NA, and it turns out to be a very long ifelse statement. 
    `df$d1<-ifelse(!is.na(df$a and !is.na(df$b), df$b-df$a)`
But the farther I get from a, the more complex the ifelse statements get. 
I also tried writing 
    `df$d1<-(!is.na(df$b))-(!is.na(df$a))`
And the result is not difference, but whether the first data point is NA or not (I get 0, 1, -1 in the d1 column).

This is how my original database is structured:

````
```a<-c(10, 20, NA, 40, 50, 60)
b<-c(5, NA, 6, 7, NA, 8)
c<-c(NA, 4, 5, NA, 7, 8)
d<-c(NA, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5)
e<-c(3, 4, NA, 5, 6, 7)
df<-data.frame(a, b, c, d, e)```
````

This is how I need the result to look:

````
```d1<-c('-5','' ,'' , '-33','', '-52')
d2<-c('', '-16', '-1', '', '-43', '0')
d3<-c('', '5', '3', '0', '-1', '-3')
d4<-c('-2', '-5', '', '-2', '0', '2')
df1<-data.frame(d1, d2, d3, d4)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option.  We loop through the rows with `pmap` (or using `apply` from `base R` with `MARGIN = 1`), get the `diff`ernce of adjacent non-NA elements ('i1'), bind the rows (`pmap_dfr`), `select` the column names in the correct order and `rename` the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
pmap_dfr(df,  ~ {
       x <- c(...)
      i1 <- !is.na(x)
       diff(x[i1]) %>% 
    as.list}) %>%       
  select(sort(names(.))) %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('d', seq_along(.)))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#     d1    d2    d3    d4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    -5    NA    NA    -2
#2    NA   -16     5    -5
#3    NA    -1     3    NA
#4   -33    NA     0    -2
#5    NA   -43    -1     0
#6   -52     0    -3     2
```

NOTE: Here, by default, the missing elements will be filled with `NA`.  It is better not to use blank strings (`""`) as it changes the column type from `numeric` to `character`

---

If we have `NA` only rows, find the

```
pmap_dfr(df,  ~ {
     x <- c(...)
    i1 <- !is.na(x)
    if(any(i1)) {
     diff(x[i1]) %>% 
     as.list
    } else set_names(rep(list(NA_real_), length(x)-1), names(x)[-1])}) %>%       
  select(sort(names(.))) %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('d', seq_along(.)))
```

Comment: @tadat IN that case, just subset the data `pmap_dfr(select(df, a, b, c, d, e), ~ `

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That works. Just one question: suppose I have other columns in the df data frame that I am not including in the difference calculation. How would I specify that I only want to perform this calculation on columns a, b, c, d, and e?

Comment: @tadat I already mentioned that you can specify the columns of interest by `select`ing

Comment: Thanks! I do have one more question: I have some cases where all the columns (a, b, c, d, and e) are blank. Currently, those rows are just omitted. Is there a way to retain those rows when calculating the difference, just with NA in all the difference columns?

Comment: you can have `if(all(is.na(x))) NA`